# Empty vector of type <stuff*>

Tags: c++

I have a vector populated with objects:

```
std::vector<Stuff*> stuffVector;
```

and am trying to delete all elements of it using a cleanup function

```
void CleanUp()
{
    for (std::vector<Stuff*>::size_type i = 0 ; i < stuffVector.size() ; i++)
    {
        stuffVector.erase(stuffVector.begin()+i);
    }
    cout << stuffVector.size() << endl;
    if (stuffVector.size() == 0) cout << "Vector Emptied" << endl;
}
```

This always reports back with a size of however many objects are in the vector, and doesn't actually seem to delete anything at all. It's odd as a similar function works elsewhere to delete a specific object from the vector:

```
void DestroyStuff()
{
    if (stuffVector.size() > 1)
    {
        for (std::vector<Stuff*>::size_type i = 0 ; i < stuffVector.size() ; i++ )
        {
            if(stuffVector[i]->CanDestroy())
            {
                stuffVector.erase (stuffVector.begin()+i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above works fine, but CleanUp() does not. Why might this be happening?

Comment: Do not manage resources manually. Use a smart pointer. Problem solved.

Comment: Question is *unclear*. Do you want to to `delete p` for each `p` in the vector, or do you just want to empty the vector, or do you want to empty vector and also have its buffer deallocated, or what? Answer depends on *what effect you want*.

Comment: "I have a vector populated with objects" -- no, you have a vector populated with pointers, which is the problem. Create a vector of objects instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
for (std::vector<Stuff*>::size_type i = 0 ; i < stuffVector.size() ; i++)
{
    stuffVector.erase(stuffVector.begin()+i);
}
```

Imagine the vector has elements `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` in it. After the first erase (`i==0`), it would be `1, 2, 3, 4`. The second erase with `i==1` would render it `1, 3, 4`, and in the end, it will end up as `1, 3`.

The best alternative for clearing a vector would be

```
stuffVector.clear()
```

and, if that's unsuitable:

```
stuffVector.swap(std::vector<Stuff*>());
```

or

```
while(!stuffVector.empty()) stuffVector.pop_back();
```

or

```
stuffVector.erase(stuffVector.begin(), stuffVector.end());
```

Other means to delete contents of a vector are left as an exercise for the reader :)

If you wanna do something else with the elements before clearing them (... like deleting the objects the pointers point to) I'd suggest doing that separately and then clearing the vector as separate actions. Or swap with an empty vector and do whatever you want with the swapped vector.

Comment: This is a solution to clearing the `vector` (which is what the OP asked), but its worth noting that `DestroyStuff()` will invoke undefined behavior by operating on invalid iterators after the first `erase()`

Comment: @JaredC: It won't - OP's code doesn't hold any iterators that could be invalidated.

Answer (score 2):

When you erase an element, the size of the vector changes.  So your loops are skipping over elements since on some iterations you `erase()` and `i++`.

Additionally, to remove every element of a `vector` the `clear()` function is useful.  Also, the standard way of looping through all elements in a vector is to use iterators.  Your code should look like this:

```
void CleanUp()
{
    for (std::vector<Stuff*>::iterator it = stuffVector.begin() ; it != stuffVector.end() ; it++)
    {
        /* .. do something to each element to prepare it for removal */
        delete *it;         // clean up resources?
    }
    stuffVector.clear();
    cout << stuffVector.size() << endl;
    if (stuffVector.size() == 0) cout << "Vector Emptied" << endl;
}
```

and

```
void DestroyStuff()
{

    for (std::vector<Stuff*>::iterator it = stuffVector.begin() ; it != stuffVector.end() ; /*done inline*/)
    {
        if((*it)->CanDestroy())
        {
            it = stuffVector.erase(it);
        }
        else
            ++it;
    }
}
```

This loop works because `erase()` returns an iterator to the next element in the list.

Comment: Shouldn't the `stuffVector.emd` be `stuffVector.end`?

Answer (score 1):

```
stuffvector.clear();
```

(min. length bah!)

Comment: the clear function does clear all the contents of the container. then you can free the pointer (if that's how you allocated space for the container).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with CleanUp() is vector::erase() does not call delete to free pointers or object destructors. It just drops the pointers and leaks memory.

Answer (score 0):

Calling erase on an itertaor will invalidate the iterator

```
 stuffVector.erase(stuffVector.begin()+i);
```

followed by the following in for loop

```
 i++
```

A pointer, after delete, may not even be read or copied.  Destruction invalidates the iterator
The following may help

```
for(it = Entities.begin(); it != Entities.end();)
{
   if(...) //Conditional deletion
   {
       delete * it;
        it = Entities.erase(it);
   }
    else
    {
        it++;
     }
}
```

Comment: @Neera: Is this behavior defined when you use the same iterator after the `erase()` call?  Should that iterator be assigned to the result of `erase()`, or post-incremented like `erase(it++)`?

Comment: Postincrement returns an unmodified copy of its operand before incrementing.  Postincrement  performs the increment before calling erase(), when it is  valid to do so, while passing (a copy of) the unincremented iterator to that function. Also std::vector::erase returns a new, valid iterator to the element after the erased one (or end).  Both these postincrement/returned itertaor form erase are also valid ways of deleting elements from vector

Comment: Thanks for the suggested for loop. Implementing it tells me that 'it' was not declared in this scope however.

Comment: @bo23 I have just tried to give the sequence to follow for remove idiom